What is the usage of に in this sentence? How is it used?
This dialog is all presented by the same person, who is narrating a creepy story
「友から聞いた妙な話がある————」
「曰く、友の友のそのまた友に、　変わり者の音楽家がいるそうな」
「雨の日の軒下に毒餌を撒き、　雨宿りにきた猫たちを殺す————」
「さて、その音楽家は何故、　猫を殺したと思う？」
What I'm stumbled in how to take the second sentence exactly?
曰く、友の友のそのまた友に
can be taken as "According to him, a friend of a friend of  a friend..."
変わり者の音楽家がいるそうな
An eccentric musician exist.
But what is not clear me, what is the function of に here?  I assume it's に音楽家がいる like "the musician existed here" but how can it be used with a living being?

I think you can understand this as an extension of に as a location marker. If you're comfortable with sentences like 私には夢がある or 彼には子供が3人いる, you can understand the sentence in question the same way. Similarly, you can say 親戚に芸能人がいます, 知り合いにパソコンに詳しい人はいませんか, and so on.

In 私には夢がある, に marks the owner (私の夢). Similarly, in 彼には子供が3人いる, the relationship can be expressed as 彼の子供。
In the 親戚 and 知り合い sentences, on the other hand, に does not mark the owner, assuming I understand the meaning correctly: (subject) has a relative who is a celebrity; do you know anyone who is good with computers?. So, does に actually have the same function here?

@DavideBordoni It's true that English "has" works only for some cases, but that does not mean these に are different. に is not a possession marker, and 彼には友達がいる does not mean he owns his friend.
